# Windows 10, Date/Time changes by itself. Keeps jumping a full month ahead. Ideas?

Tags: windows-10, time

Logged on twice and each time the date jump from current day in May to middle of June. Ideas?

Comment: Are you syncing with one of the internet clocks?

Comment: You could also check to see if the Windows Time service is running by following these [steps](https://organicweb.com.au/20209/general-technology/windows10-time/)

Comment: Go to date and time settings and set a time server from pool.ntp.org

Answer (score 0):

Check your date and time sync configuration:

Control panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Date and Time

[image]